# Looping zero-padded numbers in swift - Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, animated, leading-zero, zero-pad

Under the SKSpriteNode class, you can do the following to animate an object

```
private func animate(){
  var playerTextures:[SKTexture] = []
  for i in 1...3 {
    playerTextures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "image00\(i)"))
  }
  let playerAnimation = SKAction.repeatActionForever(
    SKAction.animateWithTextures(playerTextures, timePerFrame: 0.1))
  self.runAction(playerAnimation)
}
```

The above code can animate an object using the sequence of images. Here the image files would be image001.png image002.png image003.png

Here come's my question, how can I animate images if the file names are
image001.png
image002.png
...
image009.png
image010.png
image011.png
image012.png
The key point here is the problem with the zero paddings. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you will only have three digits number you could add your pictures that way:

```
for i in 1...3 {
    let imageNumber = String(format: "%03d", i)
    playerTextures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "image\(imageNumber)"))
}
```

This will give you image001, image002 and image003

This requires that you `import Foundation` at the beginning of your swift file

Comment: thanks, btw, you may have a typo "image\(String(format: "%03d", i))"

Comment: I edited my answer, I think it should be okay now and easier to read ;)

Comment: Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)